# Reverse of aggregate / by?

Tags: r, merge, aggregate, expand, r-factor

I have a question and hope that some of you can help me. The issue is this: for a given data frame that includes a vector y of length n and a factor f with k different levels, I want to assign a new variable z which has length k to the data frame, based on f.

Example:

```
 df <- data.frame(y=rnorm(12), f=rep(1:3, length.out=12))
 z  <- c(-1,0,5)
```

Note that my real `z` has been constructed to correspond to the unique factor levels, which is why `length(z) = length(unique(df$f)`. I now want to create a vector of length n=12 that contains the value of `z` that corresponds to the factor level `f`. (Note: my real factor values are not ordered like in the above example, so just repeating the vector `z` won't work),

Now, an obvious solution would be to create a vector `f`outside the data frame, merge it with `z` and then to use `merge`. For instance,

```
 newdf <- data.frame(z=z, f=c(1,2,3))
 df <- merge(df, newdf, by="f")
```

However, I need to repeat this procedure several thousand times, and this `merge`-solution seems like shooting with canons on microbes. Hence my question: there almost surely is an easier and more efficient way to do this, but I just don't know how. Could anyone point me in the right direction? I am looking for something like the "inverse" of `aggregate` or `by`.

Comment: You may want to [edit] the question with a language tag to increase the chances of it getting the attention of users able to answer it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming that the values in z correspond to the f levels

```
df <- data.frame(y=rnorm(12), f= sample(c("a","b","c"),12,replace=T))
z  <- c(-1,0,5)
df$newz<-z[df$f]
```

In case this is not clear: this works because factors are stored under the covers as integers.  When you index z with that vector of factors you are effectively indexing with the underlying integers, which point to the right z value for that factor value.

Comment: That is even easier than I imagined it would be. Thanks!